# Django export data to csv file with CBV

Tags: django, export-to-csv

I'm looking for `export data` from database to different files formats (.csv, .json, .xls ...).

The idea should be : user go to a new template and can access to many download buttons. When it clicks on one, he downloads the file with the choosen format.

I have this view :

```
class Exports(ListView):
    template_name = 'exports.html'
    context_object_name = 'exports'

    def export_categories_csv(request):
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="categories.csv"'

        writer = csv.writer(response)
        writer.writerow(['id', 'name'])

        categories = Category.objects.all().values_list('id', 'name')
        for category in categories:
            writer.writerow(category)

        return response

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        self.export_categories_csv()
        return super(HomeView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

My urls.py file looks like this :

```
url(r'^exports$', Exports.as_view(), name='exports'),
```

And the associated template :

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block main %}

    <a href="{% url 'exports' %}" class="btn btn-default">Export all categories in CSV</a>

{% endblock main %}
```

How I can create different buttons and display these buttons in the same page ? And how I can make the links between each button and each functions inside the same class.

Up to now, the issue is :

> Exports is missing a QuerySet. Define Exports.model, Exports.queryset,
>   or override Exports.get_queryset().

Comment: Well you do part of the `ListView` logic yourself, you should specify the `model = Category` attribute to the CBV.

Comment: Furthermore you should *patch* the `.get(..)` function to return the content, now you specify `export_categories_csv`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok, but if I need to export data from different models on the same page, not just `Category` but `Animal`, `Food` too ?

Comment: then you make an *abstract* `ExportView`, and subclass it with the correct model/queryset.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok I will make more searches, a bit obscur again for myself